# QuiltView Error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'scrollOrientation'

Tags: android

I want to use the [QuiltView lib](https://github.com/jacobmoncur/QuiltViewLibrary) in my Android project. 
When I try the demo, I've no problems, but when I want to use it in my project I've got this error :

```
error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'scrollOrientation' in package 'com.jake.quiltview'
```

I've just include libs (QuiltViewLib & GridLayoutV7) in my project...

So, have you got an idea ?

Comment: Please post your layout file!

Comment: Hi! Is demo project running perfectly? i am getting some error while implementing demo project

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to fix the namespace. The XML he used references his own project. You have to change it to reference yours. I had this issue too.

Change

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/com.jake.quiltviewsample
```

To:

```
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/lib/com.package.class
```

Obviously changing it to match your project package. :)